# Can I completely remove a <small> element from my JQuery result?

Tags: jquery

Here's my HTML:

```
<li id="home">
<a data-href="/C">X<br>
<small>Y</small></a>
</li>
```

I used the following to empty what is between the  tags.

```
a = li.parent().parent().children("a, span:not('.toggle')");
var text1 = a.find('small').empty();
var text2 = a.html();
```

This gave me:

```
<li><a>X<br>
<small></small></a></li>
```

However this still gives me the tags. Is there another way that I could do this instead of using `.empty()` some way that would remove the `<small>` tags and also the `<br>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.find('small').remove();` will remove the `small` tag with it's content.
[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pCpzT/)

Comment: Thanks. If I want to remove the br as well can I chain this?

Comment: @Anne Sure, but you don't need to cascade, you just have to change the selector to `$('small, br')`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
a = li.parent().parent().children("a, span:not('.toggle')");
var text2 = a.text();
```

http://api.jquery.com/text/